# Disconnections with Azure Postgres DB

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, azure

I'm facing a problem of disconnections with azure Postgres DB,
We are working on a java/Spring-boot project, and it's deployed in azure platform,

So, we have a method that read data from a file that contains almost 4 000 000 lines,

We use org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager to execute queries on the database (CopyIN and copyOUT),
So when we start importing data from the file to the database, the copy is canceled after some time with the error below:

```
2021-09-02 09:41:18 UTC-61309b1d.d7bf8-STATEMENT:  COPY COP_TEST FROM STDIN DELIMITER '|' NULL 'null'
2021-09-02 09:41:18 UTC-61309b1e.d7bfc-LOG:  could not send data to client: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.   
2021-09-02 09:41:18 UTC-6107b789.24-LOG:  parameter "default_transaction_read_only" changed to "on"
2021-09-02 09:41:18 UTC-61309b1e.d7c04-FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-09-02 09:41:18 UTC-61309b1f.d7c08-FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-09-02 09:41:18 UTC-61309b1e.d7c04-LOG:  could not send data to client: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.
```

This is our hikari Conf, as you can see i have tried all the possible values

```
hikari:
      #validation-timeout: 5000000
      #connection-timeout: 6000000
      #poolName: Hikari
      auto-commit: false
      #leak-detection-threshold: 600000000
      #minimum-idle: 15
      #maximum-pool-size: 30
      #idle-timeout: 2400000
      #maxLifetime: 30000**
```

I have updates also the variables "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout" and "statement_timeout" on the cloud with the value: 1800000ms, but it has no effects,
And when i'm testing my application with my local DB , it's working fine, i don't have any disconnections,

I'm confused, i don't know if it's Hikari who close the connections, or it's the server side.

Could you please help me resolve this issue ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Whose log is it that you have shown us?

Comment: It's the log of postgres in azure

Comment: Then it is not hikakri that is doing it.  Maybe azure autoscaling?

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that there is a connection issues it may occur by a Firewall or Scaling.

Check here the limitations of Azure Database for PostgreSQL [Limits - Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Single Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-limits)

**For Scale operations**

1. Dynamic scaling to and from the Basic pricing tiers is currently not supported.
2. Decreasing server storage size is currently not
   supported.

Check the Troubleshoot connections of Azure Database for PostgreSQL [Troubleshoot connections  Azure Database for PostgreSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-troubleshoot-common-connection-issues#steps-to-resolve-persistent-connectivity-issues)

1. Set up [firewall rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-manage-firewall-using-portal) to allow the client IP address. For temporary testing purposes only, set up a firewall rule using 0.0.0.0 as the starting IP address and using 255.255.255.255 as the ending IP address. This will open the server to all IP addresses. If this resolves your connectivity issue, remove this rule and create a firewall rule for an appropriately limited IP address or address range.
2. On all firewalls between the client and the internet, make sure that port 5432 is open for outbound connections.
3. Verify your connection string and other connection settings.
4. Check the service health in the dashboard. If you think there’s a regional outage, see [Overview of business continuity with Azure Database for PostgreSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-business-continuity) for steps to recover to a new region.

Check the above possibilities if still issue persist refer [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-for-postgresql/are-you-running-into-postgres-connection-issues-on-azure/ba-p/1994913)